# Compiling java file and passing file to stdin gives error

Tags: java, command-line, bufferedreader

I've created a java program in Intellij Idea.

In this program I have a function to read a file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    \\Some code
    readInput(args);
    \\Some code

}

private static void readInput(String[] args) throws IOException {
    \\Some code
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    \\Some code
}
```

I've set Intellij a file as an argument. The file is `input.txt`.

If I run this, the program reads the file and works as expected.

I'm now trying to achieve the same thing using Windows command line.

My files are in to packages. Something like this

`...\Dir\packageOne\ClassOne.java`

`...\Dir\packageOne\ClassTwo.java`

`...\Dir\packageOne\ClassThree.java`

`...\Dir\packageTwo\ClassFour.java`

`...\Dir\packageTwo\ClassFive.java`

`` `...\Dir\input.txt ``

First I start by compiling all classes with this command:

```
...\Dir>javac packageOne/*.java packageTwo/*.java
```

And then try to run the file like this:

```
...\Dir>java packageOne/ClassOne < "...\Dir\input.txt"
```

I'm gething `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` at the function `readInput(args);` at the line `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));`

Isn't this the way to compile the files and pass a file using command line?

Comment: take out the `<` operator

Comment: "<" is not needed.. Its not Linux.. Ur using Windows..

Comment: @epoch. Thanks. Youre right. Don't you want to give an answer since you were the first to provide me with the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The less than operator is not needed for passing input, instead `args` will contain the passed arguments separated by a space character:

```
java MyClass 1 2 3 4 5
```

`args` will now contain:

```
args[0] -> "1"
args[1] -> "2"
args[2] -> "3"
etc...
```

so you just need to remove the `<` character

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `<' character in between. Just put

```
java ClassName inputFileLocation
```